# Integral of $c(m,r)$

Tags: integration

Let $$\frac{1}{c(r,m)} = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{e^e}}\rho^{m-1}\frac{1}{\rho \log\frac{1}{\rho}(\log\log\frac{1}{\rho})^{2-m+r}}d\rho$$
where $m\geq1$ and $r>0$.
So, how can i find the integral of the $c(m,r)$ based on $m$ and $r$.
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What is $c(r,m)$ supposed to be? And from where did this integral appear? Some context would really be helpful here.

Comment: The function define $$f(\|x\|) = c(m,r)\frac{1}{\|x\|}\frac{1}{(\log\log\frac{1}{\|x\|})^{2-m+r}}\mathbbm{1}_{\|x\|\leq 1}$$. In here, $\|x\| = \rho$, i want to solve the integral of $c(m,r)$ in terms of incomplete gamma function

Comment: Well, if it helps, your integral is equivalent too: 
$$-\int_e^\infty e^{-(m-1)t}\ln^{m-r-2}(x)\frac{dt}{x}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{m-1}\int_{(m-1)e}^\infty e^{-x}\ln^{m-r-2}\left(\frac{x}{m-1}\right)\frac{dx}{x}$$
And now you can consider the integral:
$$\int_{(m-1)e}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{m-1}\right)^{s-1} e^{-x}dx=\frac{1}{(m-1)^{s-1}}\Gamma((m-1)e;s)$$
And take $m-r-2$ derivatives with respect to $s$ then set it to $0$. But I daresay it's a terrible way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your result and effort, where $s$ is coming from and did you chance boundaries?